# appointment confirmations via email

Tags: google-schemas

I am interested in finding out how I can send my business customers appointment confirmation emails to their Gmail accounts and have their Google calander automatically populate the info and give them a reminder without any action required on their part. I know it's possible as I received such emails from companies that have done this. Can anyone please help? I'm not the most computer savvy person so I will need an explanation. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@carl grassl You will want to use [**EventReservation**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) for appointment confirmations.

When you send your customer an email confirmation with **EventReservation**, this will automatically populate the info of the appointment in their Calendar, additionally, it will also trigger a [Google Now card](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards/) of the appointment.

Check out this tool below, logging in with your personal Gmail account:

http://gmail-actions.appspot.com

Once you've logged in, load the sample "Event card." You can send yourself an **EventReservation** email.

When you feel that you got everything locked in with your production email client, you'll have to register with Google to use schemas. Make sure your email is authenticated (DKIM/SPF). You can get all the details here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google